# C - Pattern Printing within a Switch Menu

Tags: c, menu, switch-statement

I am new with C but have to do a project for school. I want to print out a menu in which the user selects a pattern which then gets printed out. It should be something like this:

[Program running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWyoj.jpg)

But as you can see when I select the pattern for a second time it does not show the pattern. It only shows a blank space. Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int numerodefilas;

    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de filas/longitud del objeto:\n");
    scanf("%d", &numerodefilas);

    int fila, columna, eleccion;
    int numerodecolumnas = numerodefilas;   

    do {
        printf("1: Triangulo\n");
        printf("2: Piramide\n");
        printf("\nSalir\n");
        scanf("%d", &eleccion);

        switch (eleccion) {
        case 1:
            for (fila = 1; fila <= numerodefilas; fila++) {
                for (columna = 1; columna <= numerodecolumnas; columna++) {
                    printf("X");
                }
                printf("\n");
                numerodecolumnas--;
            }
            break;
        case 2: /* Second choice */
            break;
        case 3:
            system("cls");
            printf("Adios!\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("No seleccionaste una opción correcta!");
            break;
        }
    } while (eleccion != 3);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

The identifiers are in spanish, since I have to do it in spanish. Just a quick explanation about the names:

1. numerodefilas = numberoflines
2. numerodecolumnas = numberofcolumns
3. fila = line
4. columna = column
5. eleccion = choice
6. "Ingrese la cantidad de filas/longitud del objeto" = Enter the amount of lines/longitud of the object"
7. Triangulo = Triangle
8. Piramide = Pyramide
9. Adio = Bye

I don't know if somebody can still help me? If you need more explanations just let me know! Am I doing something wrong? Is there something wrong with the pattern printing? I would really appreciate any help at all.

Comment: Use a debugger to trace the execution of your program. Posting on Stackoverflow should be a last resort after attempting to debug as much as you can yourself. You have not demonstrated much debugging effort.

Comment: There is no reason to do `numerodecolumnas--;`

Comment: The program's output may be in Spanish, but forcing the programmer to use Spanish for identifiers is silly: it reduces readability for other programmers across the world.  I work in France with French developers, but insist on identifiers to have meaningful English names.

Comment: @chqrlie 
I know it is quite stupid. Sadly my teachers want me to do it this way. Their argument is that if we copy any code we will at least have some work in changing the identifiers.

Comment: @TheUnriashol: that's a poor argument. I hope they do not favor the use of non ASCII letters is identifiers, which is supported by recent versions of the C Standards and some of the common compilers. While there is some beauty in `#define π 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288`, you should avoid `int sim = 1, não = 0;`

Comment: @chqrlie Like I said, I would also rather do it in english. What you are saying is correct. That is why you dont see any accents (tildes) or any ñ in my code. Thankfully it was just simply a loop error rather than a poorly written identifier, which was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@R.Eduard Big thanks for pointing out the flaw in my code, I finally got it to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int numerodefilas;

    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de filas/longitud del objeto:\n");
    scanf("%d", &numerodefilas);

    int fila, columna, eleccion,numerodecolumnas;  

    do {
        printf("1: Triangulo\n");
        printf("2: Piramide\n");
        printf("\nSalir\n");
        scanf("%d", &eleccion);

        switch (eleccion) {
        case 1:
            numerodecolumnas=numerodefilas;
            for (fila = 1; fila <= numerodefilas; fila++) {
                for (columna = 1; columna <= numerodecolumnas; columna++) {
                    printf("X");
                }
                printf("\n");
                numerodecolumnas--;
            }
            break;
        case 2: /* Second choice */
            break;
        case 3:
            system("cls");
            printf("Adios!\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("No seleccionaste una opción correcta!");
            break;
        }
    } while (eleccion != 3);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

The change I had to make was reset the numerodecolumnas value before restarting the loop. I did this quite simply by removing int numerodecolumnas=numerodefilas; and adding it before the for loop.

Thank you once again!

Answer (score 1):

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Your problem may be caused by the fact that you do not reset the columns to their default value ?

You substract the columns with `numerodecolumnas--;` which works the first time but the second time the value is already 1 or 0 and therefore your loop might not work .

Comment: Ohh yeah you might be right there. Thank you for the tip. I will see how I can get it to work. Thank you.